# jQuery (Append)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For instance I have this html code

```
<div class="messageContainer">
  <div class="message">
  </div>
</div>

---Here

<div class="messageContainer">
  <div class="message">
  </div>
      <here> :)
</div>
```

Now I need to create a div with some information located in the text ("---Here").
Is there any way how obviously by using jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `after()` command:

```
$("#messageContainer").after("<div>");
```

Though in your example, this will add it after every messageContainer. You will need to adjust the selector appropriately. So you'd want `#messageContainer:first` to add it after only the first container, for example.

`before()` is also available.

Comment: There's also `$('<div').insertAfter('#messageContainer');` and `insertBefore()` ;)