# How to replace a property name in an Javascript object

Tags: javascript

i am wondering it's there a way too loop throught the all the object and to get the property and select the property to replace with another name object?

So far i manage to get the property name and i can select them in my dropdown [name, lastname and size], but i cannot figure out how to replace the property itself based on what i have select. Exemple: [name, last name, size] --> [firstname, last name ,size]

```js
var tempData = [{
  "name": "Andy",
  "lastname": "Hello",
  "size": "176cm"
}, {
  "name": "John",
  "lastname": "doo",
  "size": "180cm"
}, {
  "name": "Karen",
  "lastname": "World",
  "size": "186cm"
}, {
  "name": "Alex",
  "lastname": "Roy",
  "size": "196cm"
}]
for (var i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
  for (var p in tempData[i]) {
    $('#title').find('select[name="title-select"]').append($('<option/>', {
      value: p,
      text: p,
      id: p
    }));
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
  for (var p in tempData[i]) {
    $('#parent').find('select[name="parent-select"]').append($('<option/>', {
      value: p,
      text: p,
      id: p
    }));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title">
  <select name="title-select">
    <!-- title option -->
  </select>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <select name="parent-select">
    <!-- parent option -->
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing to point out, I don't think your example code works. Secondly, are you trying to replace the object's property name itself? Or just the name that is shows in the dropdown?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks, i fix the code, i forgot to put the jquery library, i want to replace the object property itself based on what i select.

Comment: Why i still have a -1.... @JonathanBrooks

Comment: I don't know! I'm not an admin and it isn't my downvote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery (Append)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955152/jquery-append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
var tempData = [{
  "name": "Andy",
  "lastname": "Hello",
  "size": "176cm"
}, {
  "name": "John",
  "lastname": "doo",
  "size": "180cm"
}, {
  "name": "Karen",
  "lastname": "World",
  "size": "186cm"
}, {
  "name": "Alex",
  "lastname": "Roy",
  "size": "196cm"
}];

tempData.forEach(function(o) {
  o.firstname = o.name;
  delete o.name;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i have been looking for